# Using Virtual Reality to visualize mathematical concepts

Tags: geometric-topology, visualization, programming

I hope this is an appropriate place to ask this question. I have some experience in 3D graphics programming, and I'm interested in [creating mathematical models in virtual reality](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/mathematicians-create-warped-worlds-in-virtual-reality1/). Especially topology and geometry, which seems like something that would be much more approachable when visualizing in three dimensions (i.e. rather than a 2D rendering on a screen of a complex 3D object). Especially for non-Euclidean geometries. There's also probably a decent subset of students that get stuck with the symbology who would otherwise be drawn to the visual aspects of mathematics if they had access.

Are there frameworks or libraries that already exist that could help me get started? In theory I could build it all from the ground up using something like Unity or another 3D graphics engine, but having something with mathematical capabilities built in would be a huge time saver. Not to mention, while I certainly have a love of math, my education is in engineering, so being able to abstract away some of the more complex mathematics would be very useful, though I realize there's still I lot I would need to learn (and am happy to do so). Just wondering if there are any shortcuts I can take on the technological side of things to get things started.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it myself, but "Processing" might be of interest:

https://processing.org/

Comment: Interesting, thanks. They certainly have some of the tools that I need but it doesn't seem to be designed around VR use. They seem to have some Android VR examples though, so I'll definitely take a look.

Comment: Good luck ! It would be great to see what you came up with. Also, Mathematica is good at taking care of a lot of abstract maths, and might be useful for creating models and exporting them to standard formats. It has quite a steep learning curve however.